# NSDateFormatter doesn't support long-form day periods ('b' or 'B')

Tags: ios, date, localization, nsdateformatter, hebrew

NSDateFormatter doesn't seem able to use the 'B' or 'b' format specifiers.  'B' is a little like 'a' (am/pm), but it outputs things like "at night" or "in the morning".

For example, this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale* locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];
NSString *dateTemplate = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"h:mmB" 
                                                         options:0 
                                                         locale:locale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateTemplate];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
NSString* now = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"String:\t%@\ndateTemplate:\t%@", 
      now,
      dateFormatter.dateFormat);
```

...prints this:

```
String: 10:23 PM         // Should be "10:23 at night"
dateTemplate:   h:mm a   // Note that 'B' turned into 'a' (am/pm)
```

Skipping dateFormatFromTemplate and putting the format directly into the formatter has the same effect.

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) say that iOS 7 and later use tr35-31.  It's unclear whether that spec supports 'B'.  The formatting table for [version 31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) mentions 'a', but does not mention 'B'.  On the other hand, the spec for [all of tr35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) does indeed mention 'B'.

If you download the [actual CLDR data](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads) for version 31, you can find dayPeriod entries for "in the evening" etc.

**The data exists; is there another formatting string I can use to get longer "day period" strings?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `B` is used for a "natural language" description of the day period. However, the problem you're experiencing is arising from using it in a date format template.

It would seem that the CLDR does not recognize that it should keep `B` in a date format string when you ask it to localize a template format. Thus, it's substituting `a` back in to the final format string.

Incidentally, if you run through `+[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`, you'll see that there isn't *any* locale that support `B` in a template string.

However, if you use `B` in a date format string directly, then it works as expected:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"h:mm B";
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Outputs:

```
12:57 in the afternoon
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get it to work in a iOS playground in Xcode 9. Sorry, the code below is in Swift, but it does seem to be working for me.

```
let loc = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
let testDF = DateFormatter()
testDF.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
testDF.locale = loc

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "h:mm B"
df.locale = loc
df.string(from: testDF.date(from: "09-21-2018 17:22")!)  // "5:22 in the afternoon"
df.string(from: testDF.date(from: "09-21-2018 19:22")!)  // "7:22 in the evening"
df.string(from: testDF.date(from: "09-21-2018 22:22")!)  // "10:22 at night"
df.dateFormat  // "h:mm B"
```